# Argument not specified for parameter in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Dear All Programmer,

I tried in the project in vb.net there is an Error but if I run it in the c# project there is no error. Is there a problem with my vb.net code?.is there another solution so that there is no error in the vb.net project?

Thanks

```
'this is the result of an error from project vb.net
Error   3   Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Sub VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(sender As Object, eventArgs As AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs)'.  C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET\Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET\Form1.vb 16  40  Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET
Error   2   Argument not specified for parameter 'eventArgs' of 'Private Sub VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(sender As Object, eventArgs As AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs)'.   C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET\Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET\Form1.vb 16  40  Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET
Error   1   'Public Event NewFrame(sender As Object, eventArgs As AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.  C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET\Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET\Form1.vb 16  9   Barcode Scanner using Webcam in VB.NET
```

```
'Code in VB.NET
 Private Sub btnStart_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        videoCaptureDevice = New VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection(cboCamera.SelectedIndex).MonikerString)
'the line of code below error
        videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame
        videoCaptureDevice.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal eventArgs As AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs)
        Dim bitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap)
        Dim reader As New BarcodeReader()
        Dim result = reader.Decode(bitmap)
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            txtBarcode.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                    txtBarcode.Text = result.ToString()
                                                End Sub))
        End If
        pictureBox.Image = bitmap
    End Sub
```

```
'Code in C#
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[cboCamera.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
            videoCaptureDevice.Start();
        }
        private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
            var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
            if (result != null)
            {
                txtBarcode.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    txtBarcode.Text = result.ToString();
                }));
            }
            pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: If you attach an event handler in code then make sure you detach it when you're done with it.

Comment: Also, if you plan to detach event handlers, it's extremely important to compile with `Option Strict On`.  Otherwise, in the event of a signature mismatch, your intended detach won't actually detach it and you may have handlers firing that aren't expected to be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you register an event hander in VB. This:

```
videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame
```

should be this:

```
AddHandler videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame, AddressOf VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame
```

Comment: thanks for your answer running without error